# Error using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been doing an Angular.js course, and now that I finished it, I wanted to give it a try and do some tests.

I used the basic html file for beginning:

```
<html ng-app="app.js">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="plugins/angular-min-1.4.3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

... which points to the simple angular app.js main module declaration:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

Nothing strange here, no? I tried making a few directives and so, but nothing worked. Then, I found this error, which appears as soon as I only have the above code. I guess it's not adding well the plugin or I'm not declaring well the app variable.

> 12:32:44.547 Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=app.js&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.3%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dapp.js%0AJ%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FAngularPruebas%2Fplugins%2Fangular-min-1.4.3.js%3A6%3A416%0Ade%2F%3C%2F%3C%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FAngularPruebas%2Fplugins%2Fangular-min-1.4.3.js%3A24%3A66%0Aa%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FAngularPruebas%2Fplugins%2Fangular-min-1.4.3.js%3A23%3A109%0Ade%2F%3C%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FAngularPruebas%2Fplugins%2Fangular-min-1.4.3.js%3A23%3A1%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FAngularPruebas%2Fplugins%2Fangular-min-1.4.3.js%3A37%3A381%0Am%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FAngularPruebas%2Fplugins%2Fangular-min-1.4.3.js%3A7%3A320%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FAngularPruebas%2Fplugins%2Fangular-min-1.4.3.js%3A37%3A229%0Aeb%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FAngularPruebas%2Fplugins%2Fangular-min-1.4.3.js%3A40%3A1%0AAc%2Fd%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FAngularPruebas%2Fplugins%2Fangular-min-1.4.3.js%3A19%3A339%0AAc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FAngularPruebas%2Fplugins%2Fangular-min-1.4.3.js%3A20%3A151%0AZd%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FAngularPruebas%2Fplugins%2Fangular-min-1.4.3.js%3A18%3A464%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FAngularPruebas%2Fplugins%2Fangular-min-1.4.3.js%3A289%3A428%0Aa%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FAngularPruebas%2Fplugins%2Fangular-min-1.4.3.js%3A176%3A73%0AGf%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FAngularPruebas%2Fplugins%2Fangular-min-1.4.3.js%3A35%3A212%0A1
>   angular-min-1.4.3.js:6:415

Why does this happen?

Comment: The module is app not app.js. Also, try including the unminified version of Angular.js - it will give you more informative errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was being really silly not adding the app.js file. Now that I added it, ng-app="app" finds it properly.

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in html.
Your app is **app**, not **app.js**.

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script src="plugins/angular-min-1.4.3.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: It still shows the same error. Nothing has changed at all.

Comment: Try to use the not-minified version of angular. The error message will get more clear.

Comment: BTW if you are getting the exactly same error, it means that you didn't change the html, as the error is mentioning `app.js` which is only in your html.

Comment: Ok, now it shows the whole error, but I still don't get why it doesn't instantiate the app module: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Have you included you app.js in your html?

Comment: Just did as I said in the answer below! Forgot about it on the beginning, sorry

Answer (score 0):

On ng-app, you must say the name of the app, in this case it's "app" and not the file. I recommend you also not using ng-app on the HTML tag.